# How to pass password to Git command from a batch file

Tags: git, batch-file, parameter-passing, git-clone

I have a simple batch file "clone.bat" withe the following script.

```
cd %1
```

`c:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" git clone %2 --branch %3`

`exit`

While running the batch file I pass 4 parameters.
%1 : local repo path, %2 : remote repo path, %3 : branch name , and %4 as password

I expect that when the Git command runs it should accept the %4 as password. However, it asks for password on the fly which I need to avoid.

I have set of only https authentication and not using SSH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github)

Comment: why don't you just generate ssh keys and put the public one in the git server? Usually this is the way to automate the git operations.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you should not need the password as Git by default will look for it in the Windows Credential Manager:

```
git config credential.helper
```

So double-check if a password is already entered there.